# Scrollable bootstrap column

Tags: bootstrap-4, scroll

I have this specific layout in an Angular component. I want the col(SCROLLABLE CONTENT) to scroll when its content exceeds the height of the MAIN CONTENT Column.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    MAIN CONTENT
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         SCROLLABLE CONTENT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the question with your coding and research efforts towards solving this issue (what you tried and link(s) to any documentation stating what you tried should have worked).

Answer (score 0):

Try .overflow-auto on the column.

Comment: Hmm then I think you would need a max-height on the main row, something along those lines.

Comment: Yeah, thought that too, but I'm trying to avoid it because the page should be fully responsive